# Bootable drive mac and put other folders

Tags: macos, backup

If I create a bootable hard drive (for example using *SuperDuper!*) will I be able to put folders on that drive (just for temporary copy reasons) or does that make it impossible to boot from this hard drive then.

Answer (score 0):

You can put additional files and folders on the bootable volume without disturbing its bootability, just as long as you don't delete, rename, or move any of the OS files and folders.

Oh, one exception: if you add bad/incompatible software into the various OS folders (e.g. any of the the Library folders), you may break the system because it'll try to load that software.